# Backend integration of Sign in with Apple

Tags: php, swift, jwt

I'm trying to build a simple backend to support sign in with Apple.
Following the documentation I was able to obtain the `authorizationCode` from the client.
The first problem is that the sdk provide that value as a `Data`.

Is it right to convert it to string with `String(data: authCode, encoding: .utf8)` or I need to use `authCode .map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }` like with the push notification token?

I think the correct way should be the first one but I'm not sure.

My backend code looks like that:

```php
    function handleRegisterTokenPost($arguments) {
        if (!isset($arguments['code'])) {
            badRequest();
        }
$key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
my
multiline
api
key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;
        $kid = 'MYKID(from developer.apple)';
        $iss = 'MYTeamIdentifier';
        $clientID = 'MyBundleID';

        $token = array(
            "iss" => $iss,
            "iat" => time(),
            "exp" => time() + 100000,
            "aud" => "https://appleid.apple.com",
            "sub" => $clientID
        );

        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key, 'ES256', $kid);
        var_dump($jwt);
        $data = [
            'client_id' => $clientID,
            'client_secret' => $jwt,
            'code' => $arguments['code'],
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'myredirecturl'
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

        $serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);
        echo $serverOutput;
```

When I try to decode the JWT token (through jwt.io) I get a decoded token very similar to the one used as example on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens) (at the end of the page)

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to encode the jwt token.

The problem is that I keep getting `{"error":"invalid_client"}`.
I have the same error even if I provide a random string as "code", that's why I think this could be an issue on how this code is generated but I'm not sure.

Does someone has an idea I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue and I'm not sure on the reason why but I was not able to sign with "Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) with the P-256 curve and the SHA-256 hash algorithm" while using `php`. Thus I tried creating the token on `ruby` which worked properly.

First install `jwt` to your locale with `gem install jwt` then use the script below.

```
require 'jwt'

team_id = ''
client_id = ''
key_id = ''
ecdsa_key = ''

headers = {
  'kid' => key_id
}

claims = {
    'iss' => team_id,
    'iat' => Time.now.to_i,
    'exp' => Time.now.to_i + 86400*180,
    'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
    'sub' => client_id,
}

token = JWT.encode claims, ecdsa_key, 'ES256', headers

puts token
```

Just so you know the token created with this script will expire in 6 months. You can change this by editing `exp` parameter yet 6 months is the upper limit Apple allows.